# Inserting serialized value into wp_postmeta using update_post_meta

Tags: wp-query, post-meta

I'm looking to insert this serialized value into a `meta_value` in the `wp_postmeta` table

```
a:1:{s:8:"quantity";s:1:"2";}
```

I've tried numerous things

Such as creating the associative array manually.

```
$defaultquantityarray =  array('quantity' => '2');
$defaultquantity = serialize($defaultquantityarray);

update_post_meta( $post_id, '_default_attributes', $defaultquantity);
```

I've also referenced the [update_post_meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) 
 documentation and found reference to something like this

```
$escaped_json = 'a:1:{s:8:"quantity";s:1:"2";}';

update_post_meta( $post_id, '_default_attributes', wp_slash( $escaped_json ));
```

and additionally with `a:1:`.

Both result in this insert into my `meta_value` row

```
s:29:"a:1:{s:8:"quantity";s:1:"2";}";
```

This is all being performed in a WP_Query loop.

How do I insert a meta_value of `a:1:{s:8:"quantity";s:1:"2";}` into my `_default_attributes` meta_key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow okay, so after posting this I almost immediately came up with the solution.

It was a combination of the two things I tried.

```
$defaultquantityarray =  array(
 'quantity' => '2'
);

update_post_meta( $post_id, '_default_attributes', $defaultquantityarray);
```

Apparently WordPress automatically serializes data in some `meta_value`s, and I was essentially serializing them twice hence the `s:29:` prefix.

Comment: arrays and objects get automatically serialized/unserialized because they are php data types being stored as strings by MySQL.

Comment: Actually really interesting, and makes sense. Thanks for the insight

Comment: You should sanitize the input data before sending it to database. Please, refer to the link for details about WordPress sensitization methods https://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data